# Including JavaScript/jQuery Object Data in <a> Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to include JavaScript object in my `<a>` tag. I want my users to be able to copy and paste the html for the `<a>` tag onto their site and edit it. They will also include a link to my `.js` script which will process it.

Right now I have the `HTML`:

```
<a id="test" href='#' jqueryData='{
    "name":"test",
    "type":"tag"
    }'>Click Here</a>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
    var target=$('#test');
    var data= $.parseJSON(target.attr("jqueryData"));
    console.log(data);
```

Which produces the desired output:

```
Object {name: "test", type: "tag"}
```

So it works fine, but I am always wondering if there is a *better* way to do this. Am I going to run into any browser support issues? I know `jqueryData` is not an official attribute of `<a>`...will that be a problem? Will I run into problems with special characters being in the data?

Thanks a ton for your help!

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the great answer(s) guys! Assuming I have 15-20 attributes to add, do you recommend approaching it with ONE jSon data like above or simply using a new attribute for each piece:

```
<a id="test" href='#'  data-name="test" data-type="tag" data-width="100" data-test="1" .... >Click Here</a>
```

Comment: You can use a `data-` attribute insteand of `jqueryData`. http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use an attribute like `data-jquery`. All `data-` attributes are designed to add, well, additional data (it's part of the HTML5 specification). Browsers won't complain.

Just make sure to escape the code to avoid issues using `escape()`, then use `unescape()` before parsing the JSON.

Comment: Additionally, if you use `data-jquery` as the attribute, you can retrieve it as `target.data('jquery')` as well as through the `attr` method.

Answer (score 0):

Proper convention with regard to inventing your own tags is to prefix them with "data-" so something like "data-jquery-data". Then you'd need to change your code to use `target.data("jquery-data")`.

Another point is that $.parseJSON throws exceptions if the string being parsed isn't JSON.  So you're going to want to do something like

```
var data;
try { 
    data = $.parseJSON(target.data('jquery-data'));
} catch() {
    if(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }   
}
```

Other than that, I think it should be pretty okay.

Answer (score 0):

You can base64 encode the object and then decode. This is perhaps not the leanest way, but it does the job. You'll need a b64 encode and decode function

```
<a data-json="eydkYXRhJzogJ3ZhbHVlJ30="></a>
var json = JSON.parse(b64Decode(object.getAttribute('data-json')));
Console.log(Object.keys(json));
```